# crontab -e fails to run

Tags: ubuntu, cron

when i run "crontab -e" i get:

```
/usr/bin/editor: line 40: /tmp/crontab.BTXqyZ/crontab: Permission denied
/usr/bin/editor: line 40: exec: /tmp/crontab.BTXqyZ/crontab: cannot execute: Success
crontab: "/usr/bin/editor" exited with status 126
```

crontab -e was working fine a few months ago. a cron job i set up few month ago is still running successfully.

i wanted to create a new cronjob for another program and i got the above error....

Comment: Cross posted here: http://superuser.com/questions/93944/running-crontab-e-permission-denied

Answer (score 1):

You have a permissions problem.  Your `/tmp` directory may be mounted `noexec` and for some reason your version of cron doesn't like that, `/tmp` may have some sort of silly permissions on it (it should be `1777`), your `/usr/bin/editor` is up the creek, or whatever `/usr/bin/editor` points to may be similarly broken.  I'd test `/usr/bin/editor` on something else to eliminate that as the source of the problem, then go to town on `/tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

May be /tmp access mode is wrong. Check it with `ls -dla /tmp`

Right mode for tmp is 1777 (drwxrwxrwt)

> $ ls -dla /tmp 
>   drwxrwxrwt 7 root root 4096 Jan 12 00:00 /tmp

Correct it with `sudo chmod 1777 /tmp`. 1 is sticky bit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit and 7 is read-write-execute for user, group, world